# REG: No result while connects NODEJS to ORACLEDB

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

**nodeJS connects to oracle**

var oracle = require('./');

```
var connectData = {
    hostname: "myhost",
    port: 1521,
    database: "mydb", // System ID (SID)
    user: "usertest",
    password: "mypass"
}
oracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {
    if (err) { console.log("Error connecting to db:", err); return; }

    connection.execute("SELECT * FROM <table_name>", [], function(err, results) {

        if (err) { console.log("Error executing query:", err); return; }

        console.log(results); //This statement's not working
        connection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing
    });

});
```

**output**-

C:\xampp\htdocs\motcua.dev\public\socket.io\node_modules\oracle>node tests-connection
    C:\xampp\htdocs\motcua.dev\public\socket.io\node_modules\oracle>

**Question**- It is exiting without giving any output please help me with this

Comment: you would need oracledb package for nodejs to communicate to oracle.
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#quickstart this should help.

Comment: i had solve this issue by installing client package